# Rails 3, prepared query not working with nil value

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

Here is my query

```
query = "(description = ? AND address1 = ?) AND (city = (?) OR old_city = (?) OR cb_city = (?))"
```

Input data :

```
office_data = {"description"=>"Europe HQ", "city"=>"Dublin", "street_1"=>nil}
```

But When I queries as

```
 office = company.offices.where(query, office_data["description"], office_data["street_1"], office_data["city"], office_data["city"], office_data["city"]).first
```

Equivalent SQL:

```
SELECT "offices".* FROM "offices" WHERE "offices"."company_id" = 6 AND ((description = 'Europe HQ' AND address1 = NULL) AND (city = ('Dublin') OR old_city = ('Dublin') OR cb_city = ('Dublin'))) LIMIT 1
```

Getting result as

```
nil
```

Though I am records in company.offices

As

```
[#<Office id: 393, company_id: 6, description: "Europe HQ", address1: nil, address2: nil, zip_code: nil, city: nil, state_code: nil, country_code: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, created_at: "2014-08-19 15:13:58", updated_at: "2014-08-19 15:13:58", cb_city: "Dublin", cb_state_code: nil, cb_country_code: "IRL", old_city: nil, region_code: nil, is_hq: nil, cb_region: "Dublin", cb_updated: "2014-04-20 10:53:24", city_uuid: "97c70aa17568ca5375122f181f0484a7", city_path: "location/dublin/97c70aa17568ca5375122f181f0484a7">, #<Office id: 389, company_id: 6, description: "Europe HQ", address1: nil, address2: nil, zip_code: nil, city: nil, state_code: nil, country_code: nil, latitude: nil, longitude: nil, created_at: "2014-08-19 15:02:44", updated_at: "2014-08-19 15:02:44", cb_city: "Dublin", cb_state_code: nil, cb_country_code: "IRL", old_city: nil, region_code: nil, is_hq: nil, cb_region: "Dublin", cb_updated: "2014-04-20 10:53:24", city_uuid: "97c70aa17568ca5375122f181f0484a7", city_path: "location/dublin/97c70aa17568ca5375122f181f0484a7">]
```

Don't What's wrong with query? Anyone knows what's wrong?

Comment: Seems you have `city: nil` in your database, however, in your query you have `city = ('Dublin') OR old_city = ('Dublin') OR cb_city = ('Dublin')`

Comment: Well, in the generated SQL you have `address1 = NULL`, which should be `address1 IS NULL`. I don't know how to solve that.

Comment: @RAJ... No Actually when I try with `office = f.offices.where(query, office_data["city"], office_data["city"], office_data["city"]).first`               I am getting result as Record, I think this is not the issue,`SELECT "offices".* FROM "offices" WHERE "offices"."company_id" = 6 AND ((city = ('Dublin') OR old_city = ('Dublin') OR cb_city = ('Dublin'))) LIMIT 1
` getting me results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mischa and @Victor, the problem is indeed "NULL =". To solve the problem change the "query" parameter as below:

query = "(description = ? AND (address1 = ? OR address1 is NULL)) AND (city = (?) OR old_city = (?) OR cb_city = (?))"

No change is required to "office_data" parameter or your query.

Similarly, you may also need to make a change for city and other parameters too. As these can also have a NULL value

Answer (score 1):

The problem is comparing address with NULL using the `=` sign - every operation besides `IS` against NULL is false. Because of that you end up with (true AND false) and (...), resulting in false.

Note that the second query you added in the comments contains no address = NULL - that's why it works in that case.